# Hive: date range is not fetching the data from the table

Tags: sql, date, datetime, hive, hiveql

I am new to this platform. Trying to accomplish a task in Hive but failing to get it done.

Have a table with the following structure:

`Table1:`

```
ID DATE       VAL1  VAL2  VAL3
01 12/12/2017 12.23 56.45 78.9
02 05/06/2019 65.88 65.22 98.22
03 09/08/2018 86.00 23.00 56.05
04 09/19/2019 34.09 75.04 77.89
05 03/16/2018 87.45 45.56 89.89
06 06/06/2018 67.66 45.00 67.90
07 01/01/2018 23.21 90.99 56.33
08 07/03/2018 67.22 67.22 33.11
09 05/13/2017 12.12 98.33 78.89
```

`DataTypes:`

```
ID   INT
DATE STRING
VAL1 DOUBLE
VAL2 DOUBLE
VAL3 DOUBLE
```

`Hive Query:`

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE DATE BETWEEN date_format(current_date + 
interval '-12' month,'MM/dd/YYYY') AND 
date_format(current_date,'MM/dd/YYYY');
```

This above query is not fetching the records from the table.

`Actual O/P:`

```
OK
Time taken: 65.515 seconds
hive>
```

`Expected O/P:`

```
ID DATE       VAL1  VAL2  VAL3
02 05/06/2019 65.88 65.22 98.22
03 09/08/2018 86.00 23.00 56.05
04 09/19/2019 34.09 75.04 77.89
06 06/06/2018 67.66 45.00 67.90
08 07/03/2018 67.22 67.22 33.11
```

Any help to point out the mistake or missed part in the query will be really helpful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The format you are using is incorrect one. Correct format is `'MM/dd/yyyy'`, not `'MM/dd/YYYY'`. Your date is not in sortable format, this is why you need to convert column date to sortable format `'yyyy-MM-dd'` before applying `BETWEEN` filter:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM Table1 
 WHERE from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(`DATE`,'MM/dd/yyyy'),'yyyy-MM-dd') BETWEEN add_months(current_date,-12) AND current_date;
```

For better understanding consider this example with comparing two dates in not-sortable format:

```
hive> select '09/19/2018' > '08/01/2019'; --bad data format
OK
true
Time taken: 5.632 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

This is why `BETWEEN` operator will work incorrect with such dates.

Let's compare the same dates in correct format:

```
hive> select '2018-09-19' > '2019-08-01';
OK
false
Time taken: 0.095 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

Also see [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) class docs as a format template reference.

Answer (score 0):

First update the datatype in `[Date]` column as `DATE or DATETIME` in your table.
then execute this query

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE DATE BETWEEN Fromdate AND Todate
```